# Get followers names and photos from Google Sign via API's

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to get the followers / following name and photos using google sign via API of an USER.
Is this possible?
I'm able to sign In but not getting the list of followers / following list.

Comment: The Google plus api is very limited. To my knowledge you cant see followers.

Comment: Thank you @DaImTo

Comment: Is this possible with Flickr/Tumblr/LinkedIn/Instagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XMPP,we can get many details of  the USER.Basically it uses Google talk authorization and user can login and get all the information.

Check out this link.
[Click here](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth)